# Type parameter inherits conflicting constraints

Tags: c#, constraints, abstract-class

I have two abstract classes as follows:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> 
{

private T ID;
private string Name;
private bool isActive;

protected MyBaseClass()
{
     Initialize(0, String.Empty, false);
}
protected MyBaseClass(object ID, string Name, bool isActive)
{
     Initialize(ID, Name, isActive);
}
protected virtual void Initialize(object ID, string Name, bool isActive)
{
   Type t = typeof(T);
   if(t == typeof(string)))
       this.ID = (T)(object)ID.ToString();
   else
       this.ID = (T)ID
   this.Name = Name;
   this.isActive = isActive;
}
}

public abstract class MyList<TKey, TItem> where TItem : MyBaseClass<TKey> {}
```

`T` and `TKey` can be `string` or numeric types.

I'm getting the following error on MyList:

> Type parameter TItem inherits conflicting constraints
>   'MyBaseClass' and 'object'.

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more detail in your code sample? The two lines you have provided compile as-is on my machine (as one would expect) so I suspect that there has to be more to the story...

Comment: I added the content of MyBaseClass in the original post

Comment: Excluding the extra parenthesis on the line `if(t == typeof(string)))`, this still compiles.

Comment: Same. This compiles fine for me with .net 4.5.

Comment: Probably you can get the root cause behind this issue at the below link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfb6s56c.aspx